# How can I display the result of steganalysis on my website using Django and HTML?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am currently developing a website for steganalysis. All codes and functions can be used appropriately, however I could not make the result appear on the page of my website. In this website, I should have produced the result of steganalysis onto the same pagee in its own section but it did not happen.  I have intergrated the index.html and views.py according to the mentioned code below.

return render(request, 'index.html')

For each tasks in views.py, I have included above code, however nothing changed. The result still does not display on the web page. The concept of the website is similar to cyberchef where it does not store any of the analysis tasks. It only perform tasks selected by user and produces the  results.